# Creating python class with required and optional attributes?

Tags: python, metaclass

I want to create multiple python classes which has alot of required and optional fields. During initialization I want to check whether all required attributes are passed and do validation of all attributes.

This is solution i came up with. But problem with this, IDEs no more auto suggests the class attributes.

Is there any better solution to handle my problem ?

```
class Field(object):
    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return instance.__dict__[self.name]


class IntField(Field):

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if not isinstance(value, int):
            raise ValueError(f'expecting integer in {self.name} got {value}')
        instance.__dict__[self.name] = value

class StrField(Field):
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if not isinstance(value, six.string_types):
            raise ValueError(f'expecting string in {self.name} got {value}')
        instance.__dict__[self.name] = value

class PropertiesCreator(type):

    def __new__(mcs, classname, baseclasses, props):
        c_props = props.get('_required_properties', ())
        for name, cname in c_props:
            props[name] = cname()

        c_props = props.get('_optional_properties', ())
        for name, cname in c_props:
            props[name] = cname()

        return super(PropertiesCreator, mcs).__new__(mcs, classname, baseclasses, props)


class Schema(object):

    _required_properties = ()
    _optional_properties = ()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for name, _ in self._required_properties:
            try:
                value = kwargs.pop(name)
            except KeyError:
                raise RequiredAttributeError("Required %s is missing" % name)
            else:
                setattr(self, name, value)

        for name, _ in self._optional_properties:
            try:
                value = kwargs.pop(name)
            except KeyError:
                pass
            else:
                setattr(self, name, value)

        if kwargs:
            raise InvalidAttributeError("Invalid items ")

    def required_attributes(self):
        return self._required_properties

    def optional_attributes(self):
        return self._optional_properties


@six.add_metaclass(PropertiesCreator)
class CheckpointSchema(Schema):
    _required_properties = (
        ("name",    StrField),
        ("is_enabled", BoolField)
    )

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CheckpointSchema, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

Comment: [Abstract Base Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, using a metaclass very often confuses you IDE, use an ABC instead. It should accomplish what you want without the confusion.

Comment: I didn't get it. Should i make PropertiesCreator class Abstract class ? Can you please give a example how it will solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The ways you  can use a metaclass to check for properties are open ended, and just code running at run time can actually define whether an argument will be required or valid. That means, there is *no* way for an IDE to possibly guess your desired verification schema and work along with it - you could only ensure it by writing an extension to your IDE that would go along with your code.

HOWEVER, there is a good chance that if an IDE imports a module containing your class using Python itself (and  not by trying to statically check the actual typed-in code), if your object-classes have a well formed `__init__` method with all required parameters as mandatory, and all optional parameters with a default sentinel value, it would work.

Therefore, you have to write your metaclass in a way it actually generates an `__init__` function with the proper signature. Although there are ways to programmaticaly  set a function signature with things from the `inspect` module, or create a function using `types.CodeType` + `types.FunctionType`, this would take  a long time to get working, and become less readable than simply composing a string with the desired method signature and use `exec` to get it rolling. Moreover, this could make use of annotations, so you can get even extra help from the IDE.

So, your code could become something like (sorry - Python 3.6 - to make this compatible with Python 2.7 as well you will need a lot more typing):

```
from textwrap import dedent as D

...
class IntField(Field):
    type_ = int

class StrField(Field):
    type = str
...


_SENTINEL = object()


def _check_attrs(**kwargs):
    self = kwargs.pop("self")
    for name, _ in self._required_properties:
        try:
            value = kwargs.pop(name)
        except KeyError:
            raise RequiredAttributeError("Required %s is missing" % name)
        else:
            setattr(self, name, value)

    for name, _ in self._optional_properties:
        value = kwargs.pop(name)
        if value is not _SENTINEL:
            setattr(self, name, value)

    if kwargs:
        raise InvalidAttributeError("Invalid items ")



class PropertiesCreator(type):

    def __new__(mcs, classname, baseclasses, props):
        c_props = props.get('_required_properties', ())
        for name, cname in c_props:
            props[name] = cname()
        required = ", ".join(f"{name}:{cname.type_}" for name, cname in c_props)

        optional = []
        c_props = props.get('_optional_properties', ())
        for name, cname in c_props:
            props[name] = cname()
            optional.append((
        optional = ", ".join(f"{name}:{cname.type_}={_SENTINEL}" for name, cname in c_props)

        namespace = {"_check_attrs": _check_attrs}

        exec(D(f"""\
            def __init__(self, *, {required}, {optional}):
                _check_attrs(locals())
        """))
        props["__init__"] = namespace["__init__"]

        return super(PropertiesCreator, mcs).__new__(mcs, classname, baseclasses, props)





class CheckpointSchema(Schema, metaclass=PropertiesCreator):  
    # Sorry - we are 18 months away from python 2 EOL . 
    # Do you really need Python 2 compatibility in a new project thic complex?
    _required_properties = (
        ("name",    StrField),
        ("is_enabled", BoolField)
    )

    # Leave __init__ undefined.  
    # if you need more code to run on `__init__`, the metaclass will
    # get a lot more complicated - maybe change th emetaclass to 
    # make use of `__new__` to init the properties, instead
    # and leave `__init__` alone.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`pyfields`](https://smarie.github.io/python-pyfields/) for this:

```
from pyfields import field, init_fields

class Position(object):
    x: int = field(check_type=True, validators=lambda x: x > 0)
    y: int = field(check_type=True, 
                   validators={'y should be between 0 and 100': lambda y: y > 0 and y < 100})

    @init_fields
    def __init__(self, msg="hello world!"):
        print(msg)

p = Position(x=1, y=12)  # ok
p.x = '1'  # raises TypeError see below
p.y = 101  # raises ValidationError see below
```

yields

```
TypeError: Invalid value type provided for '<...>.Position.x'. 
   Value should be of type <class 'int'>. Instead, received a 'str': '1'
```

and

```
ValidationError[ValueError]: Error validating [<...>.Position.y=101]. 
   InvalidValue: y should be between 0 and 100. 
   Function [<lambda>] returned [False] for value 101.
```

IDE autocompletion works once the object is created (or wherever the type is referenced), but is does not currently work for the signature of the generated constructor ; this is due to the fact that the constructor is generated, IDE has some difficulty to follow. I'll try to work with PyCharm to improve this.

See [`pyfields` documentation](https://smarie.github.io/python-pyfields/) for details. I'm the author as you might have guessed already ;)